# all arguments must have the same length e1071 svm in R

Tags: r, svm, e1071

I'm trying this code:

```
> svm.model = svm(churn~., data = train)
> svm.pred = predict(svm.model,test)
> table(pred = svm.pred, true = test)
```

But I received the following error message:

```
Error in table(pred = svm.pred, true = test_data) : all arguments must have the same length
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Thanks

Comment: It would seem that the next glaringly obvious step would be to execute: `length(svm.pred); length(test_data)`. I'm guessing one of them (probably test_data) is a data.frame for which the "length" function returns the number of columns, rather than rows, while `svm.pred` is quite possibly a vector? You _should_ have been able to detect this by first looking at `str(test_dat)` and `str(svm.predict)`.

Comment: > length(svm.pred)
[1] 9617
> length(test)
[1] 5
> nrow(test_data)
[1] 9619

svm.pred has one factor vector
whereas test is a data frame

Comment: So you probably have  NA's in your test_data that makes the prediction vector shorter. Pretty sure this is a duplicate of other questions here. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+length++predict